# SQL Server 2014 SP1 CU6 Issue with Multi-Valued Parameters (No Longer Expand)

Tags: ssrs

Since upgrading to SQL Server 2014 SP1 CU6 (from CU4) on two different servers we have encountered what appears to be a bug with multi-valued parameters in SSRS where you can no longer drag to expand them. Also you must reload the page before the drop-down will function again.

The issue seems to only affect IE11 and is ok in Chrome and did not occur before updating from CU4. If we downgrade back to CU4 then the issue is resolved again on each server tested.

I have carried out further tests and I can confirm that the drop-downs are also broken in the same way in CU7 and also SP2 so the issue appears to not have been addressed as of yet by Microsoft.

It would appear someone else is asking about the same issue here:

This is what the multi-valued drop-down looked like before:
[image: Multi-valued drop-down before CU6 applied]

This is what the multi-valued drop-downs looks like now:
[image: Multi-valued drop-down after CU6 applied]

As you can see the option to drag the selection list has gone and some of these are very long and contain long descriptions and it means there is no way to view all the text at once.

Once the drop-down has been dropped-down once you must refresh the page which is a pain as it obviously clears the selection from all parameters.

I cannot see this raised as a KB article anywhere or many posts with people experiencing this which seems surprising.

Thanks
Robin

Comment: In case anyone comes across this, I have been speaking to someone at Microsoft and it turns out this bug will be fixed in the next cumulative update although unfortunately it won't be out until next month.

These releases are:
•SQL Server 2014 SP1 CU9
•SQL Server 2014 SP2 CU2

The release date is estimated as 17/10/2016.

Comment: Could you post your comment as an answer and mark it as solution? Will help keep the tag [tag:ssrs] nice and tidy.

Comment: Hello hot2use, I have now posted the answer and marked it as the solution. Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this, I spoke to someone at Microsoft and it turned out this bug was fixed in the next cumulative update although unfortunately it wasn't out until October. These releases which resolve the issue are:

- SQL Server 2014 SP1 CU9
- SQL Server 2014 SP2 CU2

The release date was around 17/10/2016.

We have since upgraded to the latest version which is 2014 SP2 CU2 released last month and I can confirm the issue was resolved and no longer occurs in any browser.